# Open image via DIV data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Again I ask your help, I have an ftp where some music covers that I want to use http://inlivefm.6te.net/capas/.

Also I have a javascript that gives me the data of the cover link: link that he is now to provide 
http://inlivefm.6te.net/capas/I NEED YOUR LOVE.jpg
 the last song played

I use JavaScript to provide the covers

```js
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //  Defino my variable global
            var myObj = {}; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/AirPlayHistory.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('Song').each(function() {
                        //  Definimos el atributo tittle
                        myObj.tittle = $(this).attr('title');

                        $(this).find('Artist').each(function() {
                            //  Definimos el atributo artist
                            myObj.artist = $(this).attr('name');
                        });

                        $(this).find('Info').each(function() {
                            //  Definimos el atributo time
                            myObj.time = $(this).attr('StartTime');
                        });

                        $(this).find('Info').each(function() {
                            //  Definimos el atributo cover
                            myObj.cover = $(this).attr('JazlerID');
                        });

                        //  Por ultimo lo mostramos :)
                        $('.cancion').html("<p>http://inlivefm.6te.net/capas/" + myObj.tittle + ".jpg</p>");
                    });
                }
            });         
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cancion"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Knowing that `div` gives me the link of the cover, wanted to open the through image of the data provided

```html
<img src="<div class="cancion"></div>
"/>
```

The example I want is something like this:

```html
<img src="http://inlivefm.6te.net/capas/I NEED YOUR LOVE.jpg"/>
```

I'm trying to do this but I am not able to because the image does not open, so I came to ask your help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You have an IMG tag with a DIV tag inside. Was this on purpose?
HTML code is not a valid source for an image, you should give an ID to your IMG and change source with Javascript.

Comment: @goncalopinto The goal was that the div provides the link is the image opened up, it seems it was not like he was doing

Comment: Do you mean something like <div data-cover="http://inlivefm.6te.net/capas/I%20NEED%20YOUR%20LOVE.jpg"></div> ?

Comment: No, that does not work at all. You need something like `$('.cancion').html('<img src="http://inlivefm.6te.net/capas/' + myObj.tittle + '.jpg">');`

Comment: @ClaudioKing  yes, DIV cancion behind the cover link and what I wanted was to open the DIV link it to have the cover

Comment: @JohannesJander 
Even changing to like you said, the DIV recognizes jpg, but does not open the image

Comment: If I can understand you want the image to be a link and open in fullsize when you click it? If that's the case then you have to surround your IMG tag with an A tag.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want an image, which when clicked on takes you to another resource; done like this:

```
<a href='resource.URL' ><img src='image.URL' other_attributes /></a>
```

Clicking on `image.URL`  will take you to  `resource.URL`

Comment: What I wanted even though she soon opened without having to click on anything, but as I said I put the div in img leads nowhere

Comment: No, you need                                                 **src="http://inlivefm.6te.net/capas/I NEED YOUR LOVE.jpg"**

Comment: Yes, but as the xml will be active the cover will always be changing, so the importance of DIV, so it does not exchange cover and is always the same

Comment: So, you want a DIV with an image inside and make it behave as a link but without using IMG and A tags? Only the DIV? Is that it?

Comment: @goncalopinto he could use a div with a **background-image** specified in CSS, a separate class for each div !

Comment: @Arif Burhan , that's why I asked, it can be done in different ways, wrapping a DIV with a background image in a A tag it's probably the one he is looking for, of create an event in JavaScript for the DIV.

Comment: @goncalopinto I just want to open a page to appear the music cover, this is the link where you want to appear http://inlivefm.6te.net/current.php ,as you can see I apply the code and am trying to immediately open without be to click on anything.

Comment: A new webpage opens when you hover the mouse? Or an overlaying box with the image inside? Please clarify this so I can help you.
If it's hard for you to explain exaclty what you want, please include images of something similar and/or include your own drawings explaining better your idea.

Comment: I have a hover on text example - done with CSS3 and HTML5 alone **http://www.wisephoenix.org/examples/html5/RayHarryhausen3.htm** --- pink left sidebar.

Comment: @goncalopinto On page I have provided you this Javascript that produces information that is provided through <div class = "cancion"> </ div> this information refers to the last cover that touched xml http://inlivefm.6te.net/AirPlayHistory. xml and fTP where estam the covers is this: http://inlivefm.6te.net/capas/
In this case the information is div this link http://inlivefm.6te.net/capas/I NEED YOUR Love.jpg

Comment: @goncalopinto  but as the cover will always be changing (when you spend being active xml) thought using this form <img src = "<div class =" cancion "> </ div>" /> so that the cover is open as this link http://inlivefm.6te.net/exemplo.php and do the same with the other cases of automatic way, but I'm not able to open the covers.